# Ionic Cordova Custom Splash Screen with dynamic text for IOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to remove default splash screen from ionic Cordova project.

I have tried the following code but it does not work for me.

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none"/>
```

Also, I had to remove the splash screen plugin but it shows a white screen.

After that, I want to show some dynamic text which will be translated according to the country at the splash screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First changes in config.xml

   ```
   <preference name="SplashMaintainAspectRatio" value="true" />
   <preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
   <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
   <preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="300" />
   <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
   <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="true" />
   <preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
   <preference name="SplashShowOnlyFirstTime" value="false" />
   <preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
   ```
2. Create a new page for Splash-screen

   ionic g page Splash

By performing these steps I resolve same problem in IonicApp.